# delete all files within a directory that are older than 1 day

Tags: linux, bash, command-line, find

I need to ensure that I have no old files left in my directory so what I think I do is

```
find . -type f -mtime +1 -delete
```

- i got that from the find man page but then

  find . -type f -mtime +1 -exec /bin/rm

but again, now told that *find: -exec requires an argument* - didn't iI pass this. So I started Googling and I found that my command needs to look likee this:

```
find . -type f -mtime +1 -exec /bin/rm -f {} +
```

and now I'm just wondering what the two **{}** s and the **+** sign are for. Can anyone help me here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `{}` stands for the name of the file(s) found.

The `+` sign (instead of a `;`) means that this command accepts multiple file names in the same command, so that `find` can run much faster because it is run less times. The number of files added to each execution of the command is limited by the maximum length of the command line `find` is willing to use.